# What does "incognita" mean?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-gender, italian

[American Heritage Dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/incognita) reads:

> **incognita**
>
> - *adv & adj*, with one’s identity disguised or concealed. Used of a woman;
> - *n*, A woman or girl whose identity is disguised or concealed.

So, is it correct to say “Giselle Regan, an American reporter, went in incognita and used hidden cameras”?

Comment: It's an adjective, so you would probably say "she went incognita", not "in incognita"

Comment: @simchona Perhaps this is the quasi-phrasal verb, *to go in*?

Answer (score 3):

If you read *incognita* as *disguised*, which you should, then the sentence reads:

- Giselle Regan, an American reporter, went in disguised and used hidden cameras.

If that is the intended meaning, then your proofreading question is fine.

The OED gives:

> **A**. *adj*. Of a female: Unknown or disguised; having one’s identity concealed or unavowed.
>   **B.** *sb*. 1. An unknown or disguised woman or girl; one whose identity is not made known. In 18th c. used often of a sweetheart.
>  
>   2. Unknown or unavowed character or position (of a woman).

You may recognize this from the famous *terra incognita*. This is the same word as *incognito*, just put into the feminine form. The original pronunciation puts the stress on the second syllable, although you will often now hear it stressed on the penult.

Comment: *incognito/incognita* is Italian, while  *incognitus/incognita/incognitum* was Latin.

Comment: It was more for the benfit of other readers as *terra incognita* was a Latin phrase and you switched languages mid-sentence.